# How do I index a list to find a specific value and its location?

Tags: python, list, file, indexing

I am trying to write a code which will store movies on a list which I can retrieve by asking to add a movie either by its position or to check if it's on the list. So far, I have been working on the retrieving part, but I keep getting an error where "descriptor 'index' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object".
This is my code so far

```
myFile = open("movies.txt", "a")
more = "yes"
while more.lower() == "yes":
    movie = input("Please enter a movie title: ")
    myFile.write(movie + '\n')
    more = input("Would you like another item? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. ")
    find = input("Would you like to find a movie? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. ")
    myFile.close()
    if find == "yes":
        myFile = open("movies.txt")
        xlist = list[myFile]
        f2 = input("What movie would like to find?")
        f3 = xlist.index(f2)
        print(f2 + " is in number " + f3 + " on the list")
```

Comment: `list[myFile]` - that doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: Use myFile.readlines() which will read the file line by line instead of list[myFile]

Comment: Well now at this point the problem is that the output is: 'str' object has no attribute 'restrip'. Just tried the readlines() but it just says that my value (random a) is not on the list

Comment: [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), not `restrip`. r is for right and l is for left.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

In line number 11  of your code

> `xlist = list[myFile]`

for making list of word that contain in file `movies.txt` you can do something like this

> `xlist=myFile.read().splitlines()`

**CODE**

```
myFile = open("movies.txt", "a")
more = "yes"
while more.lower() == "yes":
    movie = input("Please enter a movie title: ")
    myFile.write(f'{movie}\n')
    more = input("Would you like another item? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. ")
    find = input("Would you like to find a movie? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. ")
    myFile.close()
    if find == "yes":
        myFile = open("movies.txt")
        xlist=myFile.read().splitlines()
        print(xlist)
        f2 = input("What movie would like to find?")
        f3 = xlist.index(f2)
        print(f'{f2}  is in number {f3} on the list')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Please enter a movie title: money-heist
Would you like another item? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. no
Would you like to find a movie? Enter 'yes' or 'no'. yes
['Dark', 'money-heist']
What movie would like to find?Dark
Dark  is in number 0 on the list
```

Comment: Please explain where you made changes to the original code and why. Otherwise it's just a copy/paste action for OP without any learning effect

Comment: okk thx @ThomasWeller for remining me this. just a sec i am doing the changes

Comment: I DID THE CHANGES IS IT ALRIGHT NOW @ThomasWeller

Comment: so going through the edited code, and to make sure I understand this, .splitlines() separates the lines into usable information from the file, and the squiggly brackets read the variables in a different way?

Comment: and by using f'{movie} and f'{f2}, we can connect the two for every line? It makes more sense to  do this than to parse through it using a loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: splitlines() is used to split set of wold line by line in a text file and convert that into a list

Comment: And if this ans help you please mark this ans as accepted @ASimpleWatermelon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `xlist` but in `f2`, because `input()` returns string. If entering number 2, your line would look as if you wrote:

```py
f3 = xlist.index("2")
```

Instead, cast input to integer:

```
try:
    f2 = int(input("What movie would like to find?"))
except ValueError:
    exit("Invalid number")
```